# How to call JavaScript function from Freemarker?

Tags: javascript, freemarker

I have some basic JavaScript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function someTestFunction(param1, param2) {
        //do something
    }
</script>
```

and Freemarker code:

```
<#if something==somethingElse>
    // call: someTestFunction(something, 123)
<#else>
    // call: someTestFunction(somethingElse, 345)
</#if>
```

my question is: Is it possible, and if so, how to call someTestFunction() from inside freemarker tags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Freemarker is a java templating language, meaning it is executed on the server. javascript is executed on the client (user's browser). You cannot call a javascript function from the java server in this manner.

You could do something like:

```
<script>
<#if something==somethingElse>
    someTestFunction(something, 123);
<#else>
     someTestFunction(somethingElse, 345);
</#if>
</script>
```

which means the javascript wll be executed on the client side depending on what server variable is set.